# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' using IBM Informix and WAMP

Tags: php, wamp, informix

I got error ( Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 30) when i run my php page using wamp server.

First I introduce the technology i used.

1) Adobe dreamviewer CS6

2) WAMP server 2.0

3)IBM Informix 64 bit

Steps i followed

- Install IBM Informix 64 bit
- make ODBC connection (System DNS) successsful
- download php_pdo.dll and php_PDO_Informix.dll and paste these .dll on "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\ext"
- add below lines in php.ini below extension

extension=php_pdo.dll

extension=php_pdo_informix.dll

*create below php code for connection test with IBM informix

```
<?php  $db = new PDO("informix:host=10.81.32.12; service=1504; 
database=db_cra; server='servername'; protocol=onsoctcp; 
EnableScrollableCursors=1", "Userid", "Pasw") or die("Could not connect to data); ?>
```

- restart WAMP server and execute this page

then i got this  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

Please help..I'm totally new for this Technology,
Let me know any thing you require from my side.

Comment: What's your windows version? Does it 64 bit?

Comment: Windows7 and it is 64 bit

Comment: As I know WAMP may run several versions of PHP, be sure that your current running version 5.4.12 by checking your phpinfo() output.

Comment: yes my apache version is 2.4.4 and PHP version is 5.4.12
is there any version issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not help you.

Comment: dear, my above mentioned steps are correct?

Comment: My idea to solve your issue was depend on wrong place of the driver files, and you told me that you placed them in the correct place. Last thing, in your phpinfo() output search for extension_dir.

Comment: yes sємsєм ..I got extension_dir in php.ini file.
where i add php_PDO_Informix.dll and php_PDO.dll.
extension dir (ext) and extension path("c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/ext/") is also correctly mention in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try with a DSN? http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-informix.connection.php

`$db = new PDO("informix:DSN=Infdrv33", "", "");`

where `Infdrv33` is replaced by the name of the System DSN you tested.

Comment: this time i got error as 
 Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'invalid data source name'

Comment: Did you change Infdrv33 to the name of your System DSN?

Comment: something is missing in my code or in configuration....but dont know what i missed.....
pls help.........

Comment: My only suggestion if you are still seeing 'invalid data source name' is that you made a User DSN not a System DSN. I don't think the problem is in your code or you WAMP configuration, but in the way you are referencing the driver somehow. Either the DSN you created is not available to the webserver user or the name is not quite right. http://www.geeksengine.com/article/mysql-odbc.html